How do I open multiple instances of Google Chrome instances on top of the same icon?
I prefer when multiple instances of the same program when opened are stacked on top of each other. Practically all of my programs behave this way.
However Chrome always opens the first instance as a new icon on the taskbar and then any new instances get stacked on top of that one. Is there a way to change so it always opens on top of the original icon on my taskbar?
Image below shows Opera browser with multiple instances stacked on the original and the other shows Chrome opening a new icon and then stacking more instances on that one.



Show a screenshot of the properties of the executable/shortcut you're pinning
